# SQL Query: Number of applications by month, county, & program

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to generate a list of expenditures & Number of applications by month, county & program. So far i have been able to get a list of expenditures but i am having trouble getting a list of number of applications per month. Here is the query i have thus far but the number of applications is incorrect.

```
select 
servicecounty AS County,
program,
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 1 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then    totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as January,
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 2 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as February,
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 3 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as March,
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 4 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then  totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as April,
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 5 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then  totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as May,
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 6 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as June,
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 7 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as July,
 sum(case when month(entrydate) = 8 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as August,
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 9 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as September,
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 10 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as October,
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 11 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as November,
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 12 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as December,
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 1 and year(entrydate) = 2015 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as [January 15],
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 2 and year(entrydate) = 2015 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as [February 15],
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 3 and year(entrydate) = 2015 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as [March 15],
sum(case when month(entrydate) = 4 and year(entrydate) = 2015 then totalpaymenttotal else 0 end) as [April 15]
from Sheet$
group by servicecounty, program

UNION  ALL 
select 
servicecounty AS County,
program,
COUNT(case when month(entrydate) = 1 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then ApplicationID else 0 end) as January,
count(case when month(entrydate) = 2 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then ApplicationID else 0 end) as February,
count(case when month(entrydate) = 3 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then ApplicationID else 0 end) as March,
count(case when month(entrydate) = 4 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then ApplicationID else 0 end) as April,
count(case when month(entrydate) = 5 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then ApplicationID else 0 end) as May,
count(case when month(entrydate) = 6 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then ApplicationID else 0 end) as June,
count(case when month(entrydate) = 7 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then ApplicationID else 0 end) as July,
count(case when month(entrydate) = 8 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then ApplicationID else 0 end) as August,
count(case when month(entrydate) = 9 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then ApplicationID else 0 end) as September,
count(case when month(entrydate) = 10 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then ApplicationID else 0 end) as October,
count(case when month(entrydate) = 11 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then ApplicationID else 0 end) as November,
count(case when month(entrydate) = 12 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then ApplicationID else 0 end) as December,
Count(case when month(entrydate) = 1 and year(entrydate) = 2015 then ApplicationID  else 0 end) as [January 15],
Count(case when month(entrydate) = 2 and year(entrydate) = 2015 then ApplicationID  else 0 end) as [February 15],
Count(case when month(entrydate) = 3 and year(entrydate) = 2015 then ApplicationID  else 0 end) as [March 15],
Count(case when month(entrydate) = 4 and year(entrydate) = 2015 then         ApplicationID  else 0 end) as [April 15]
 from Sheet$
group by servicecounty, program
ORDER BY program
```

Here is what the report should look like:

Expenditures by month, program & county:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ26A.jpg

Number of Apps by month, Program & county:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Aqkk.png

The table contains the following fields: ServiceCounty, TotalPaymentTotal, Program, ApplicationID, EntryDate

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Instead of adding applicationIDs together, you probably need to have 1 in the sum, so it calculates the number of lines

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are really using, either MySQL or SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your counts in the second subquery are all returning the same value.  Remember, `count()` counts the number of non-NULL values.  And, `0` is not null.

Three solutions:

- Change the `count()` to `sum()` and the `then` to `then 1`.
- Remove the `else`.
- Change the `else 0` to `else NULL`.

These are in order of my personal preference.

Comment: One more question, I am trying to format the output so that no decimals appear on the result set. I've tried, the cast function in front of the sum and after the sum but with no luck.                                            sum(case when month(entrydate) = 1 and year(entrydate) = 2014 then 1 else 0 end) as January,

Comment: @Marodr . . . That sounds like a different question.